# Android: is there a way to attach an ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback object to a single CardView?

Tags: android, swipe, android-cardview

I see the set up for an ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback object is to attach the object to the RecyclerView.  Is there a way to attach the object to a single CardView?  I would like to show the single CardView to the user with its own Activity.  I am trying to show a leave behind when the user swipes on the single CardView.  Below is the ItemTouchHelper class I am using for swiping on a CardView in the full RecyclerView list of multiple CardViews (RecyclerView Activity).

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
    super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
    if (viewHolder != null) {
        final View foregroundView = ((MyRecylerAdapter.ItemHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
    }
} 

 @Override
public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
    int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    final View foregroundView = ((MyRecylerAdapter.ItemHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;        
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
        actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
}

@Override
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {

    final View foregroundView = ((MyRecylerAdapter.ItemHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
    getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
    int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    final View foregroundView = ((MyRecylerAdapter.ItemHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;        
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
        actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
} 

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {        
    listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
}

@Override
public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
    return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
}

public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {        
    void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
}
}

// onSwiped() in the RecyclerView Activity 
// removes the CardView from the database 
// and then updates the RecyclerView's 
// adapter so the View is updated.
```

Comment: why would you want to attach `ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback` to a `CardView`?

Comment: allows me to set up very simple code for a swipe direction to remove the CardView and a leave behind for a nice animation

Comment: it will not work without `RecyclerView`

Comment: Ok, I was afraid that was the case...I appreciate your reply.